# MySQL update procedure WITH multiple CASE and WHERE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case, where-clause

the query works and updates as it supposed to, but when I tried to make it into a stored procedure, it fails with "error near WHERE". Can anyone see what is wrong please?

```
DELIMITER //
DROP procedure if exists update_trans_with_tags//

CREATE PROCEDURE update_trans_with_tags()
BEGIN
UPDATE transactions
SET trans_cat = CASE WHEN trans_desc LIKE '%abc%' THEN 1
                WHEN trans_desc LIKE '%def%' THEN 2
                WHEN trans_desc LIKE '%ghi%' THEN 4
                ELSE trans_cat
END;
WHERE trans_cat IS NULL;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the `;` off of the first `END`;  `;` still terminates statements within the stored procedure. If the hanging `WHERE` didn't prevent you from saving the procedure; the "first" statement would `UPDATE` **all** transactions.

Comment: ok, so I have no error but also 0 rows affected. This lost me, as I said earlier  if I run it as a plain query it updates everything correctly...

Comment: I am not sure what environment you are running it in but MySQL itself distinguishes between rows "affected" and "matched". If you are not "resetting" your data for testing; 0 rows affected are what I would expect for consecutive runs of such a query.

Comment: I'm using sequel pro for Mac, I've ensured all "trans_cat" fields are null, then i call this procedure using: call procName() but still nothing

Comment: You have `trans_desc` values that would cause changes to `trans_cat`?

Comment: yes, thats right, thats my expectation from this query, I was just reading some other related questions and someone suggested a scheduled event. What I really want is for records to update automatically on each insert.

Comment: If you want it to happen on insert you are better off using a `TRIGGER` `BEFORE INSERT` with a `SET NEW.trans_cat = ...`; you can use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger similarly for if/when `trans_desc` is updated.

Comment: and then add CASE after the = sign?

Comment: Yeah, basically replace the `UPDATE [a] SET [x] WHERE [y];` with an `IF [y] THEN SET [x]; END IF;`

Comment: tried this: 
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER updateCategory BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
    IF NEW.trans_desc LIKE '%123%' THEN SET NEW.trans_cat = 1;
    ELSEIF NEW.trans_desc LIKE '%abc%' THEN SET NEW.trans_cat = 2;
         END IF;//
    DELIMITER ; but still get syntax error ;/ ....... Oooops I forgot "FOR EACH ROW.... works now, many thanks :)